# Tradeoffs for NTC Thermistors regarding 10K vs 100K vs 1Meg etc

Tags: resistors, sensor, design, thermistor

I would like to make multiple strings of sensor having about 10 thermistors per string, each wired individually, but terminating at different lengths so that they're evenly spaced along each string.  This is to verify that 10 cu. yards of unknown materials having high thermal resistance reach a yet-to-be-determined target-temperature within the  65°F to 200°F range for a specified period of time. The target is currently 150°F but may change.

To reduce self-heating effects, I chose this 100K NTC thermistor:
[NTC Thermistor 100K 4250K Bead Murata NXRT15WF104FA1B040 Digi-Key 490-7169-ND](https://digikey.com/en/products/detail/NXRT15WF104FA1B040/490-7169-ND/3900396)

But I want to know if a 1Meg NTC would be better, and if there are any other factors that I really need to consider. Why not choose the 1Meg for the least self heating effect?

So then, what are the tradeoffs for NTC Thermistors regarding 10K vs 100K vs 1Meg?

I have noticed in the desktop power supplies that I work with, that the 10K NTC seem to be a de-facto standard. A really good, thorough answer to this general question might really help others as well. Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: You can easily filter noise with a cap on high R values as the rate of change is slower than noise

Comment: Thank you, Tony. But is this all I have to consider?

Comment: Sensitivity to current , input bias current, , amplification required , accuracy, range , power savings and filtering are all considered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why not choose the 1Meg for the least self heating effect?

Noise is a big reason, the thermal noise for a resistor is:

$$V_n = \sqrt{4k_BT\Delta f R}$$

so all things being the same the Vn for a 1MegΩ resistor will be 10 times higher than a 10kΩ resistor (R would be 100x more). Also the difference between 1MegΩ and 100kΩ would be 3 times. In addtiion, usually these resistors are placed in a wheatstone bridge, with a resistor in the same order of magnitude so that resistor noise will also increase (to keep the voltage range of the bridge the same) and the two noise sources will add with the sum of the squares, which will (in most cases) be up to two times the noise.

There are tradeoffs, increasing resistance means less self heating, but more noise. It is up to the designer to find out which is best for their application.

Comment: What does the delta-F mean in the noise equation?

Comment: How much effect do you reckon Johnson-Nyquist noise has on the temperature reading, say with a 1Hz bandwidth?

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany -- Not an EE. Sr. Software developer. Is the 1 Hz the frequency of sampling? Or molecular vibrations (brownian motion?)

Comment: I have more than $1,000 of ee books, and both the 2nd and 3rd ed. of Art of Electronics, but still don't understand it yet. For that I apologize. After 15 years, trying to reinvent self as firmware developer.

Comment: @sphero Temperature noise actually is a large source (if not the largest source ) of noise in the thermistor circuits I design.

Comment: @micro 1Hz is the circuit bandwidth, determined by filtering and it's the Delta f term in the equation

Comment: @VoltageSpike So if a typical NTC thermistor has 1V across it, and therefore changes about 40mV/°C and we have 105nV RMS thermal noise (1M || 1M at 130°C) over a 1Hz BW, that's not very many micro kelvins of noise. It will be lost in the 1/f noise of most op-amps.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany and that is exactly what I'm doing, is measuring uK, and I also use the lowest noise opamps I can buy

Comment: Okay, a degree C would probably be overkill for OP's application so it's not too relevant. The best I've been able to do is ~1uK/sqrt(Hz) in an AC bridge configuration. A bit challenging because the excitation is very low level.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Definitely overkill, I've ran a few lock in amplifiers also and got about that.  Usually run DC on most things because it's much easier to implement.

Comment: @Voltage Spike -- "1Hz is the circuit bandwidth, determined by filtering and it's the Delta f term in the equation" -- the circuit bandwidth of what it *could* carry, or of what it *does* carry? Determined by *my* filtering (that I must add), or the filtering *already* occurring in the circuit? (by virtue of the fact that everything has resistance, capacitance, and inductance).

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD Circuit bandwidth is determined by analog filters opamps and parasitics, but at the end of the day any filter digital or analog can cut back the noise. Usually this is done via low pass filtering and the cutoff frequency determines the bandwidth which determines the noise. A great book on this and how to calculate is analog circuits by Pease

Comment: @Voltage Spike -- Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It depends a lot on actual situation. The self-heating may or may not be significant. Remember it's the power dissipation at the temperature(s) of interest that matters, and the thermal resistance to whatever medium they are in, and the required accuracy. That's at least 3 to 5 variables when you count sensor tolerance and the circuitry involved.

Unless power is at a premium (eg. battery) lower resistance has more noise immunity and immunity to electrical leakage (for example if there is moisture).

Sometimes thermocouples are used in this type of application, not for their stellar accuracy (it's actually tricky electrically and mechanically to get good and stable readings, and cheap solutions lead to a lot of problems) but because they are mechanically quite robust and are very low impedance.

So higher design complexity and cost is traded off against superior reliability in the field.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the leakage -- hadn't thought about that, and thank you for answering!

Answer (score 1):

Thermal Sensitivity to constant current , input bias current, , amplification required ,input noise current and voltage, accuracy, range , power , cost savings and filtering are all considered when choosing the solution to meet your design specs and the tradeoffs for selection.

The electrical filter time constant ought to match the mechanical thermal time constant for optimal response time at low noise unless you can tolerate a slower response.

Start with your “must have” design specs then add “nice to haves”

Comment: I must have an accurate answer (0.1 deg F, a self-challenge).  I think that I can tolerate a slower response for a more accurate answer... Once every 1-5 minutes for each of either 60 or 120 sensors sounds okay to me. The process is in hours (>2).

Comment: i got these inexpensive digital thermometers with 3 remote sensors and one in the master and all give the same temperature with 0.1’C resolution.  So repeatability is great but accuracy is only as good as the calibration you rely on.

Comment: I can get distilled h2o and boil it for one point, and freeze it for the other point, and get my calibration, right? (Taking atmospheric pressure into account, of course, and altitude, I think).

Comment: 0.1'F is harder to achieve than 0.1'C  You should convert ;)

Comment: You're right -- i should! ;)